# Pull to refresh NOT for a ListView in Android

Tags: android

Hello I would like to implement pull to refresh in my Android App. But there are just Implimentations for ListViews. I would like to refresh TextViews because the Text in these TextViews is parsd from an XML(online) so whenever I change the XML and you would pull to refresh, the TextViews would be updated. Is it possible to impliment that. Are there similar projects or gits?

Thanks!

Edit:
So basically I just want the pull to refresh animation.

Comment: I suggest to look into code of implementation you've mentioned.

Comment: Just adapt it to TextView: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/blob/master/pulltorefresh/src/com/markupartist/android/widget/PullToRefreshListView.java

Comment: Started to look for it several minutes after you posted this question... nice timing:D

Comment: https://github.com/fruitranger/PulltorefreshListView is a another implementation of mine. Smooth and multi-touch support.

Comment: Chris Banes' implementation of pull-to-refresh is the best solution for you. Here is a complete guide how to implement pull to refresh in android application. Here is the link to the article link: [Android Pull to Refresh](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would definitely take a look at [Chris Banes' implementation of pull-to-refresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). His code does not only include this interaction style for `ListView`, but also `GridView` and [`WebView`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshWebView.java).

Especially the latter will be of interest in your case, since it's an example implementation of pull-to-refresh for a view that does *not* use an adapter for its content. If you look at the source code, you'll see that every concrete pull-to-refreh view in Banes' project extends from a generic [`PullToRefreshBase`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshBase.java), which contains most of the logic for animation and refreshing. The benefit of having that base class is that doing the same thing for any other type of view, e.g. a `TextView`, should be pretty straightforward.

The only drawback of this approach is that the implementation is a wrapper for other views, meaning you'll have write a couple of extra lines to get the actual view. So it's not a full drop-in replacement. However, its functionality and features far exceed that little inconvenience. :)