# Swipe to Refresh Layout without ListView

Tags: android

I want to refresh my page but I don't have something like a `listview` or `recyclerview`. I want to swipe down to refresh the fragment. There should be also an animation.
Is it possible to use the Swipe to Refresh module without any `listview` and so on

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use with **LinearLayout, RelativeLayout** also. See below code for more details,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        // Other child views
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is not only meant for listview / recycler view .  It can have either scrollview or adapterview enclosed .     Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971722/4781390

Comment: Hello @Tanuj. Just providing the links wont be good enough. if possible, please try to provide some code samples and then provide a link so that the person who has asked the question has a better understanding of the point. If you want tips on how to answer the question, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface) says in the "Add the SwipeRefreshLayout Widget" that it only supports ListView and GridView it supports other Layouts as well.

> Remember that SwipeRefreshLayout only supports a single ListView or
> GridView child.

On the previous page of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe) (Overview) it links to an [example App](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/) which shows that it is actually supported:

> A sample which shows how to use SwipeRefreshLayout to add the
> 'swipe-to-refresh' gesture to a layout with multiple children,
> enabling the ability to trigger a refresh from swiping down on the
> visible view. In this sample, SwipeRefreshLayout contains a scrollable
> GridView, along with a TextView empty view.

so I tried it out with constraintLayout and it worked

```
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/myConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp">
            
        ...
```

But you have to set the refresh state by hand back to false

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout")
    myUpdateOperation()
}
```

like this:

```
fun myUpdateOperation() {
   ...
   swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
}
```

Comment: maybe the wording "it only supports a single ListView" is a bit misleading. which can cause confusion that developers might think it only supports ListView as Layout, but what it actually says it supports all kind of child layouts BUT in that child layout only one ListView is allowed